# How to fix list of VPN providers?

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn

I am trying to install CheckPoint Capsule VPN on my private computer, a Windows 10 Home x64 Version 2004 machine.

According to the docs (and this is how it works on another computer of mine), I should be able to pick Capsule VPN as a VPN provider when setting up a new VPN connection in Windows's control panel. Unfortunately, that list keeps showing only one entry, "Windows (integrated)".

I have tried rebooting after installing Capsule VPN, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling Capsule VPN, but to no avail.

*Unfortunately, CheckPoint does not appear to offer any customer support unless you're a representative of a company in some way, otherwise I might have posted to their forums. Also note that I strongly suspect the issue is not directly within the CheckPoint software, but at least partially in my own system, and thus nothing my employer's IT department wants to deal with.*

**Is there anything I can do to force Windows to reset the list of VPN providers, or find out why a given VPN provider is apparently skipped despite having been installed?**

**Machine with problem:** Windows 10 Home, v2004 from 2020-11-22, OS Build 19041.630 + Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.31.0

**Machine where it works:** Windows 10 Pro, v20H2 from 2020-06-21, Build 19042.630 + Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.31.0

Comment: Please provide specific details as to the version, license, and update level of the two computers you're working with here.

Comment: @music2myear: I've added some version information from the OS.